# If you short an ETF, who pays its MER?

Tags: stock-market

I don't understand how [u/Cruian's comment](https://old.reddit.com/r/investing/comments/ioggru/if_someone_shorts_an_etf_who_pays_the_mer/g4dow8r/) answers the original questions in that Reddit post.

> The expense ratios are taken from the fund's holdings directly, you never see the change in your account directly.

1. So does the borrower of the ETF pay the [Management Expense Ratio ("MER")? The lender?
2. If the borrower must pay the lender the dividends, is the borrower credited the MER? Or is the borrower debited the MER?

Comment: Please write out the context of the user's comment in the actual question that you are posting here on StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

As the answer says, the management fee is directly taken from the fund’s assets. The only way that *anyone* “pays” the fees is via lower returns. There is no cash flow to pay the fee.